# Flexible bar button item now displayed on UIToolbar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I know it may seem very simple and has been asked many times but i can't get it to work .I want to add two buttons to my toolbar. One on the right side and the other one on the left. Here is the code but the flexible one which is supposed to show up on the right side doesn't appear at all. Here is the code:

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextResult:)]];

UIBarButtonItem *done=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:self action:@selector(showSearch:)];
[done setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel"]];
[items addObject:done];

[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` instead of `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`

Code:

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextResult:)]];

UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:space];

[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSearch:)]];

[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

Reference : [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The done button is a space. Therefore it won't show up.

Comment: @dasdom: Yeah, corrected that. I was editing when you added comment. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

The item with the system item `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` is a space, not button object. Therefore it does show up. It's just no button.

Change your code to

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextResult:)]];

UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:space];

[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSearch:)]];

[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

Comment: They still show up next to each other on the left side of the toolbar!

Comment: Change the type of the space to `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace`.

Comment: it should be flexible space instead of fixed space! Thanks anyway